# Git - Limit number of revisions in advance?

Tags: git, version-control, binary-files

I searched for the exact same term I titled this question with, but all I found were questions regarding the cleanup of git repositories which contain to many revisions of too many or especially too big files.

However, what I am looking for is an option to keep git repositories from entering this state beforehand, something like

```
filesize > X mb => keep at most n revisions
filename matches *.foo => keep at most m revisions
...
```

Isn't there an option to configure git in such a way in the first place? Do I really have to wait until the repo fills up and then go through the tedious process of `git-filter-branch` and its kinfolk?